# How to rotate a cubeMap with ShaderMaterial

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I create a sky box like [this example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_shaders_ocean) . My problem is that when i try to rotate the "skyBox" the cube is rotating but the material is fixed positioned at the sides without rotating. The example uses THREE.ShaderMaterial.

How can i rotate the material with the cube?

The code i used:

```
skyBox.rotation.x = Math.PI /2; //before adding the skyBox to the scene
```

and nothing happened. Then i tried at the render function:

```
skyBox.rotation.x += 0.1;
```

and i saw that the cube was rotating independently from the material..

the code is here: "view-source:http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_shaders_ocean.html"(copy paste with the view-source:)

Comment: show us your code you have treid so far.

Comment: normally when you rotate a mesh his material also should rotate.

Comment: i updated it to the question :)

Comment: did you try an other material like `MeshFaceMaterial`?

Comment: Thx didn't thought of that :P (silly) i just deleted the skyBox and the water shader works just perfect.. I'll find my own skyBox now :D

Comment: The problem still exists.. Probably need to change something from the Shader Material on what world is the skyBox loaded ex. xyz or xyz!